# R: eval(parse(...)) is often suboptimal

Tags: r, parsing

```
require('fortunes')
fortune('106')
Personally I have never regretted trying not to underestimate my own future stupidity.
   -- Greg Snow (explaining why eval(parse(...)) is often suboptimal, answering a question triggered
      by the infamous fortune(106))
      R-help (January 2007)
```

So if `eval(parse(...))` is suboptimal what is another way to do accomplish this?

I am calling some data from a website using RCurl, what i get after using `fromJSON()` in the rjson package is a list within a list.  Part of the list has the name of an order number that will change depending on the order.  The list looks something like:

```
$orders
$orders$'5810584'
$orders$'5810584'$quantity
[1] 10

$orders$'5810584'$price
[1] 15848
```

I want to extract the value in `$orders$'5810584'$price`

Say the list is in the object `dat`.  What I did to extract this using `eval(parse(...))` was:

```
or_ID <- names(dat$orders) # get the order ID number
or_ID
"5810584"
sell_price <- eval(parse(text=paste('dat$',"orders$","'", or_ID, "'", "$price", sep="")))
sell_price
15848
```

What would be a more optimal way of doing this?

Comment: doesn't work because or_ID is a character and not numerical.
Using, dat$orders[[1]]$price would work

Comment: Use `match` to get the position of the name in `names(dat$orders)`.

Comment: @Kev You can index a list using a character argument.  I just recreated your list and tried my suggestion and it worked.  If it doesn't work for you then could you paste a reproducible example in so we can actually work with some of the data you have?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually the list probably looks a bit different. The '$' convention is somewhat misleading. Try this:

```
dat[["orders"]][[ or_ID ]][["price"]]
```

The '$' does not evaluate its arguments, but "[[" does, so `or_ID` will get turned into  "5810584".

Comment: Isn't this functionally identical to @Dason 's comment?  Tho' I understand your point: the `[[` allows you to generalize to `dat[[foo_ID]][[or_ID]][[bar_ID]]`

Comment: True. `x[["a"]]` is `x$a`. I was trying to emphasize that point that "[[" allows you to mix levels of evaluation: use either quoted values or symbols that will get evaluated. The x$a formalism is misleading in that it leads the new user to think there might be evaluation of the `a`, when the opposite is the case.

Comment: Or `dat[[c("orders", or_ID, "price")]]`

Comment: Thanks, @hadley. I sometimes get confused about what "[[" can really do. For some reason I rarely succeed with that multiple arguments to "[[" formalism. So apparently I have been applying it to the wrong problems.