# how to access global/outer scope variable from R apply function?

Tags: r, scope, apply

I can't seem to make apply function access/modify a variable that is declared outside... what gives?

```
    x = data.frame(age=c(11,12,13), weight=c(100,105,110))
    x

    testme <- function(df) {
        i <- 0
        apply(df, 1, function(x) {
            age <- x[1]
            weight <- x[2]
            cat(sprintf("age=%d, weight=%d\n", age, weight))
            i <- i+1   #this could not access the i variable in outer scope
            z <- z+1   #this could not access the global variable
        })
        cat(sprintf("i=%d\n", i))
        i
    }

    z <- 0
    y <- testme(x)
    cat(sprintf("y=%d, z=%d\n", y, z))
```

Results:

```
    age=11, weight=100
    age=12, weight=105
    age=13, weight=110
    i=0
    y=0, z=0
```

Comment: You need to pass the variables to `testme`, and then to `apply`: `testme <- function(x, z) {` and `apply(df, 1, function(x, i, z) {}, i, z)`

Comment: @bdemarest:  that won't work as the value of `i` will be reset at iteration of `apply` (ie, for every row of `df`).  I think the OP wants to track which row they are on

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, you are quite right. Probably the OP would be better off not using `apply`, but instead a standard `for` loop: `for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {...}`. Currently, we can only guess at the underlying problem he/she is trying to solve.

Comment: this was only a test snip to demonstrate the problem i had :-) It turns out that I should return the results back to the caller i.e. assign the result of the apply call to another variable.  That's a better functional style.

Answer (score 43):

Using the `<<-` operator you can write to variables in outer scopes:

```
x = data.frame(age=c(11,12,13), weight=c(100,105,110))
x

testme <- function(df) {
    i <- 0
    apply(df, 1, function(x) {
        age <- x[1]
        weight <- x[2]
        cat(sprintf("age=%d, weight=%d\n", age, weight))
        i <<- i+1   #this could not access the i variable in outer scope
        z <<- z+1   #this could not access the global variable
    })
    cat(sprintf("i=%d\n", i))
    i
}

z <- 0
y <- testme(x)
cat(sprintf("y=%d, z=%d\n", y, z))
```

The result here:

```
age=11, weight=100
age=12, weight=105
age=13, weight=110
i=3
y=3, z=3
```

Note that the usage of `<<-` is dangerous, as you break up scoping. Do this only if really necessary and if you do, document that behavior clearly (at least in bigger scripts)

Answer (score 8):

try the following inside your apply.  Experiment with the value of n. I believe that for `i` it should be one less than for `z`.

```
         assign("i", i+1, envir=parent.frame(n=2))
         assign("z", z+1, envir=parent.frame(n=3))
```

---

```
testme <- function(df) {
    i <- 0
    apply(df, 1, function(x) {
        age <- x[1]
        weight <- x[2]
        cat(sprintf("age=%d, weight=%d\n", age, weight))

        ## ADDED THESE LINES
         assign("i", i+1, envir=parent.frame(2))
         assign("z", z+1, envir=parent.frame(3))

    })
    cat(sprintf("i=%d\n", i))
    i
}
```

### OUTPUT

```
> z <- 0
> y <- testme(x)
age=11, weight=100
age=12, weight=105
age=13, weight=110
i=3
> cat(sprintf("y=%d, z=%d\n", y, z))
y=3, z=3
```

Comment: I would use `assign` over `eval(parse(...))`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, I had originally put `assign` in the answer and then edited it to `eval(parse((.))`.  Why your preference?

Comment: I guess religious reasons. See the entry on `fortune`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025031/r-evalparse-is-often-suboptimal I wonder if this question sparked the question made by @CarlWitthoft a few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647046/avoiding-the-infamous-evalparse-construct

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, there are certainly quite a few questions today on it.  I [added one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse#comment18731187_13649979) myself, and @DWin made a pretty good argument.  Changed the above back to `assign()`

Comment: @RicardoSaporta `eval(parse(...))` allows addressing elements of a list as well, while `assign` doesn't support that, so I actually prefer the former option