# Assignment with lapply?

Tags: r, lapply

Why does this not work ?

```
data1<-data.frame(x=1:5,y=2:6)
onevector<-c(1,2)
lapply(1:length(onevector),function(i) {data1[,i]<-data1[,i]-onevector[i]})
```

data1 remains unchanged...

I try to substract one element to each column of my dataset data1, I want to do :

```
data1[,1]<- data1[,1] -1 (which is working out of the lapply)
data1[,2]<- data1[,2] -2
```

My question is more about understanding the difference between lapply and for than about an alternative way to implement this, so please elaborate your answer if you want to answer.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, what is your expected output?

Comment: You have to assignt the result back to `data1`: `data1[] <- lapply(1:length(min),function(i) {data1[,i]<-data1[,i]-min[i]})`

Comment: the affectation should already do that, no ???

Comment: @mtoto, it is pretty obvious but I described the 3 lines of code for you

Comment: No, the object in the global environment is not changed by the `lapply`. Btw, you could do this using `data1[] <- Map("-", data1, min)`

Comment: @docendodiscimus, I am sorry this is where I get lost, if I can make an affectation in the lapply (there is no error returned), why the affectation isn't effective ?

Comment: What I don't undestand is the difference between a loop and the lapply, but I know that we should prefer apply in R rather than loops

Comment: Inside the `lapply` call you modify a _copy_ of `data1`, i.e. not the original object that is in the global environment. If you want to change the original object, you have to assign the result of the lapply call to that object in the global environment

Comment: @docendodiscimus thanks for the map function I didn't know of !!

Comment: `lapply` is conceptionally different from a `for` loop. You are trying to use it like a `for` loop, which can't work. `lapply` is much more in line with functional programming, e.g., it applys a function on each element of its first parameter and changes to local objects in a function have no effect on global objects.

Comment: @Roland, thanks Roland, but in this case, shouldn't I get an error for trying to do affectation inside a lapply ?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "affectation".

Comment: @Roland the "<-" operation

Comment: You could have a closer look at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

Comment: Local assignments are lost when you exit the function. `<-` actually works on a copy there.

Comment: See e.g. the example which begins with "_Let’s depict that graphically with a simpler function_" in [the link @docendo discimus suggested](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html).

Comment: Ok thank you for your suggestions I will have a look

Answer (score 1):

```
data1<-data.frame(x=1:5,y=2:6)
min<-c(1,2)
s <- sapply(1:length(min),function(x) rep(x,dim(data1)[1]))
data1 <- data1-s
```

This will create a new matrix s that is made up of columns of the values of your min vector. Subtracting this from data1 will yield your result.

Or use the solution by docendo discimus which is much more elegant:

```
data1 <- as.data.frame(Map("-", data1, mn))
```

Comment: You can avoid the `as.data.frame` call by using `data1[] <- Map("-", data1, min)`. The empty brackets `[]` will keep the structure of data1 (i.e. a data.frame)

Comment: Very elegant solution indeed.

Comment: Yes I do prefer the solution of @docendodiscimus, or I can do a loop, but my question was more about understanding than implementing.

Comment: My guess would be that the function inside lapply modifies a "new" data1 in local scope and does not touch the previously exsisting data1 in local scope. This question seems to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640157/how-to-access-global-outer-scope-variable-from-r-apply-function