# For loop - select time window from day column

Tags: r, for-loop, time, dataframe, window

I need to adjust a code, which works perfectly with my dataframe (but with another set up), in order to select a 2 days time window from the column Day. In particular I am interested in the 1 day prior day0 (i.e. i - 1 and i, where i is the day of interest) and its (i - 1) values contained in the column Count have to be added into the day 0 (i) col Count.

Here an example of my dataframe:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
        Station   Day           Count
    1    33012  12448               4
    2    35004  12448               4
    3    35008  12448               4
    4    37006  12448               4
    5    21009   4835               3
    6    24005   4835               3
    7    27001   4835               3
    8    25005  12447               3
    9    29001  12447               3
    10   29002  12447               3
    11   29002  12446               3
    12   30001  12446               3
    13   31002  12446               3
    14   47007   4834               2
    15   49002   4834               2
    16   47004  12445               1
    17   51001  12449               1
    18   51003   4832               1
    19   52004   4836               1", header = TRUE)
```

my output should be:

```
           Station    Day           Count
        1    33012  12448               7
        2    35004  12448               7
        3    35008  12448               7
        4    37006  12448               7
        5    21009   4835               5
        6    24005   4835               5
        7    27001   4835               5
        8    29002  12446               4
        9    30001  12446               4
        10   31002  12446               4
        11   51001  12449               1
        12   51003   4832               1
        13   52004   4836               1
        14   25005  12447               0
        15   29001  12447               0
        16   29002  12447               0
        17   47007   4834               0
        18   49002   4834               0
        19   47004  12445               0
```

I am trying this code, but it doesn't work with my real dataframe:

```
for (i in unique(df$Day)) {
    temp <- df$Count[df$Day == i]  
    if(length(temp > 0)) {  
    condition1 <- df$Day == i - 1   
    if (any(condition1)) {
       df$Count[df$Day == i] <- mean(df$Count[condition1]) + df$Count[df$Day == i]
       df$Count[condition1] <- 0
            }
         }
}
```

The code seems right and it has sense but my output is not.

Can anyone helps me?

---

@aichao code works good.

In the case that I want to consider the previous 30 days (i.e. day-30, day-29, day-28, ...., day-1, day0) is there any quick way to do it, instead of creating 30 if statements (conditions)?

Thanks again @aichao for your help.

Comment: You could check `roll_apply` or `rollmean`

Comment: why is 12447 = 0? Shouldn't it be 6?

Comment: 12447 = 0 because I will consider the day from the top to bottom. And once the day -1 have been taken into account (i.e. take the value in Count and add it to day 0 Count) I will assign them a 0 value. So, in order, 12448 - 12447 and 12446 - 12445.

Comment: @user181187: your update is neither sorted by `Count` nor by `Day`. In the last line of my answer, I sort the result by `Count` in descending order. You can ignore the `print` and set the resulting data frame `df` to a new data frame `dfSort`. To sort by `Count`, followed by `Day`, in descending order, use `dfSort <- df[order(df$Count, df$Day, decreasing=TRUE),]` instead of just `dfSort <- df[order(df$Count, decreasing=TRUE),]`. For ascending order, just drop the `decreasing=TRUE` argument. Let me know if this is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what you want on the sample data you gave

```
for (i in unique(df$Day)) {
  temp <- df$Count[df$Day == i]
  if (any(temp > 0)) {
    condition1 <- df$Day == i - 1
    condition1[which(df$Day == i - 1) < max(which(df$Day == i))] <- FALSE
    if (any(condition1)) {
      df$Count[df$Day == i] <- mean(df$Count[condition1]) + df$Count[df$Day == i]
      df$Count[condition1] <- 0
    }
  }
}
print(df[order(df$Count, decreasing = TRUE),])
##   Station   Day Count
##1    33012 12448     7
##2    35004 12448     7
##3    35008 12448     7
##4    37006 12448     7
##5    21009  4835     5
##6    24005  4835     5
##7    27001  4835     5
##11   29002 12446     4
##12   30001 12446     4
##13   31002 12446     4
##17   51001 12449     1
##18   51003  4832     1
##19   52004  4836     1
##8    25005 12447     0
##9    29001 12447     0
##10   29002 12447     0
##14   47007  4834     0
##15   49002  4834     0
##16   47004 12445     0
```

A key requirement gleamed from your comment that was missing from your implementation is that only days that are further down the data frame (in rows) are considered in determining the previous day and its count. That is, you are processing the data frame rows as if they were ordered in time and not considering the values in the `Day` column as an ordering of time. Therefore, for `df$Day = 12449` there is no previous day to consider since all rows with `df$Day = 12448` precedes it. As a result, the `Count` for `df$Day = 12449` remains at `1`, and more importantly, the `Counts` for all rows that have `df$Day = 12448` are not to be zeroed out after processing `df$Day = 12449`.

To implement this, we need to further filter `condition1` so that we set to `FALSE` all rows for which `df$Day == i - 1` (previous day) that precedes the highest row for which `df$Day == i` (day of interest) using the line

```
condition1[which(df$Day == i - 1) < max(which(df$Day == i))] <- FALSE
```

Note that this solution assumes that same values for the `Day` column in the data frame are lumped together as blocks of rows as is in your sample data. Otherwise, your `for` loop over `unique(df$Day)` needs to be reconsidered completely and replaced with a loop over rows in order to track the current row for the day of interest in the data frame.

In addition, a minor bug in your code was in the line

```
if(length(temp > 0)) {
```

The intent was to check if there are any rows for which the `Count` is greater than `0` for the day of interest. However, conditional operators in R are vectorized such that `temp > 0` returns a vector of booleans that is the same length as its input `temp`. Therefore, `length(temp > 0)` will always return a positive number unless `temp` itself is of length `0` (i.e., empty). To get what you intend, the line is changed to

```
if(any(temp > 0)) {
```

**Update:** new requirement regarding multiple previous days

The simplest way to address the new requirement is to put the body of code within the `if (any(temp > 0)) {...}` block into a function, call it `accumulate.mean.count`, and apply this function over a collection of previous days using `sapply`. The modifications are:

```
accumulate.mean.count <- function(this.day, lag) {
  condition1 <- df$Day == this.day - lag
  condition1[which(df$Day == this.day - lag) < max(which(df$Day == this.day))] <- FALSE
  if (any(condition1)) {
    df$Count[df$Day == this.day] <<- mean(df$Count[condition1]) + df$Count[df$Day == this.day]
    df$Count[condition1] <<- 0
  }
}

lags <- seq_len(30)

for (i in unique(df$Day)) {
  temp <- df$Count[df$Day == i]
  if (any(temp > 0)) {
    sapply(lags, accumulate.mean.count, this.day=i)
  }
}

print(df[order(df$Count, decreasing = TRUE),])
```

Notes:

1. `lag` is the number of days previous to (i.e., that lag) the current day. A `lag = 1` means the previous day, and a `lag = 2` means two days previous, etc. `lags` is a collection of these. Here, `lags <- seq_len(30)` is a sequence from `1` to `30` over which `accumulate.mean.count` is applied, which is what you want. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega) for an excellent overview on the `*apply` family of R functions. Note that `lags` need not be a sequence but just a collection of integers such as `c(1, 5, 10)` for the previous day, 5 days previous and 10 days previous. It does not even have to be positive if you want to roll in future days, but should not be zero.
2. Because of the [lexical scoping rule of R](https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/lexical-scope-and-function-closures-in-r/), setting `df$Count`, which is a variable outside the scope of `accumulate.mean.count`, within the function `accumulate.mean.count` requires `<<-` instead of `<-`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640157/how-to-access-global-outer-scope-variable-from-r-apply-function) for an explanation and note the dangers of using `<<-` mentioned there.

I do not have enough data to test `lags <- seq_len(30)`, but for `seq_len(1)`, I recovered the original result, and for `seq_len(2)`, I got

```
##   Station   Day Count
##1    33012 12448    10
##2    35004 12448    10
##3    35008 12448    10
##4    37006 12448    10
##5    21009  4835     5
##6    24005  4835     5
##7    27001  4835     5
##16   47004 12445     1
##17   51001 12449     1
##18   51003  4832     1
##19   52004  4836     1
##8    25005 12447     0
##9    29001 12447     0
##10   29002 12447     0
##11   29002 12446     0
##12   30001 12446     0
##13   31002 12446     0
##14   47007  4834     0
##15   49002  4834     0
```

which I believe is what you would want.

Comment: thanks @aichao, the adjustments work good. In the case that I want to consider the previous 30 days (i.e. day-30, day-29, day-28, ...., day-1, day0) is there any quick way to do it, instead of creating 30 if statements (conditions) ?

Comment: @user181187: sorry for not responding sooner. Is it my understanding that you want to nest a loop for process the "lag" in days within your current loop? That is, we are still going from top to bottom in the outer loop and considering only days that are further down the data frame (in rows) in determining a collection of previous days and their counts (inner loop)?

Comment: hi @aichao and thanks. yes, the procedure is the same as for day -1 (your answer) and I am now asking if it is possible to compress in a 1 condition a time lag of 30 days prior day 0, instead of creating 30 different if statements (conditions).

Comment: thanks from the deep of my heart. I hope to become good as you with R.

Comment: @user181187: you are very welcome. Please let me know if there are any further questions regarding this.

Comment: hi, I just updated the question because I need to sort the dataframe by Count and Day columns.