# Assigning 1 or 0 conditionally to a new column based on values from another dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` with 32,000 entries. Here's a sample:

```
# df1
MINEVENT MAXEVENT      EVENTRANGE NUMEVENT cplt_flag
 2680001  2680051 2680001-2680051       51         0
 2680001  2680051 2680001-2680051       51         0
 2680001  2680051 2680001-2680051       51         0
 2680001  2680051 2680001-2680051       51         0
 2680001  2680051 2680001-2680051       51         0
 2680001  2680051 2680001-2680051       51         0
```

and another with a list of 157 values. Here's a sample:

```
# df2
source_id
   211535
   211535
   211535
   211536
   211536
   211536
```

I want to read from the `source_id` and test whether the value falls between `MINEVENT` and `MAXEVENT`. If `TRUE` then I want to enter a value `1` into `cplt_flag`, else `0`.

I have a code using `if-else` statements but it runs super slow for the `32,000` entries. Also, I have been trying to use functions and apply functions but cannot get this to work.

I'm looking for an efficient way to get this done.

Comment: @Arun The magic power of the r-gold badge ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dataset doesn't really have any cases where there'll be a `TRUE` scenario.. But here's a solution using the new non-equi joins feature from the current development version of data.table, v1.9.7. See installation instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

```
require(data.table) #v1.9.7+

setDT(df2)
setDT(df1)[df2, cplt_flag := 1, on = .(MINEVENT <= source_id, MAXEVENT >= source_id)]
```

For each row in `df2`, matching row indices from `df1` are extracted where the condition provided to `on=` argument is satisfied. And on those row indices, `cplt_flag` is *updated in-place* with `1`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using a `match.criterion` function and one of the *apply* functions that should be faster than looping. I've added some additional rows of data to test (not exhaustive but illustrative):

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
                  MINEVENT MAXEVENT      EVENTRANGE NUMEVENT cplt_flag
                  211535   211634  211535-211634        100         0
                  2680001  2680051 2680001-2680051       51         0
                  2680001  2680051 2680001-2680051       51         0
                  2680001  2680051 2680001-2680051       51         0
                  2680001  2680051 2680001-2680051       51         0
                  2680001  2680051 2680001-2680051       51         0
                  2680001  2680051 2680001-2680051       51         0
                  2680101  2680151 2680101-2680151       51         0", header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "
                  source_id
                  211535
                  211535
                  211535
                  211536
                  211536
                  211536
                  2680051", header = TRUE)

match.criterion <- function(source.id, df1) {
  matches <- which(df1$MINEVENT <= source.id & source.id <= df1$MAXEVENT)
  df1$cplt_flag[matches] <<- 1
}

sapply(df2$source_id, match.criterion, df1 = df1)
print(df1)
##  MINEVENT MAXEVENT      EVENTRANGE NUMEVENT cplt_flag
##1   211535   211634   211535-211634      100         1
##2  2680001  2680051 2680001-2680051       51         1
##3  2680001  2680051 2680001-2680051       51         1
##4  2680001  2680051 2680001-2680051       51         1
##5  2680001  2680051 2680001-2680051       51         1
##6  2680001  2680051 2680001-2680051       51         1
##7  2680001  2680051 2680001-2680051       51         1
##8  2680101  2680151 2680101-2680151       51         0
```

Notes:

1. The key here is to understand [R's scoping rule](https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/lexical-scope-and-function-closures-in-r/). To modify a variable outside the scope of the function, use `<<-` instead of `<-`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640157/how-to-access-global-outer-scope-variable-from-r-apply-function) for an explanation, and heed the warning concerning using `<<-`.
2. This assumes that `df1$cplt_flag` is initially all zeroes as the `match.criterion` only sets the rows that match to `1`. That is, the rows of `df1` that do not match the criterion for each value of `source_id` is left alone.

Still another vectorizing solution that uses `foreach` instead of one of the *apply* functions is:

```
require(foreach)
foreach(source.id = df2$source_id) %do% match.criterion(source.id, df1)
```