# In R Add Columns From a Different Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm an R noob!  I'm trying to use one dataframe as metadata to create columns in another dataframe.  I'm using apply but the columns aren't getting created.  Ideas?

```
meta <- data.frame(colname = c("a","b","c"))
frm <- data.frame(z=c(1,2,3))
frm["y"] <- 1
colnames(frm)
apply(meta, 1, function(x) {
  frm[x["colname"]] <- 1
})
colnames(frm)  #hoping for a/b/c columns now
```

Which outputs:

```
> meta <- data.frame(colname = c("a","b","c"))
> frm <- data.frame(z=c(1,2,3))
> frm["y"] <- 1
> colnames(frm)
[1] "z" "y"
> apply(meta, 1, function(x) {
+   frm[x["colname"]] <- 1
+ })
[1] 1 1 1
> colnames(frm)  #hoping for a/b/c columns now
[1] "z" "y"
```

UPDATE: found the answer here:
[how to access global/outer scope variable from R apply function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640157/how-to-access-global-outer-scope-variable-from-r-apply-function)

Needed to access variables outside the scope of apply using <<-

```
meta <- data.frame(colname = c("a","b","c"))
frm <- data.frame(z=c(1,2,3))
frm["y"] <- 1
colnames(frm)
apply(meta, 1, function(x) {
  frm[x["colname"]] <<- 1  #DBL ARROW DID IT
})
colnames(frm)  #hoping for a/b/c columns now
```

Answer (score 1):

The `colname` in 'meta' is `factor` class, so we need to convert this to `character` and use that to create new column in 'frm'

```
frm[as.character(meta[[1]])] <- 1
head(frm,2)
#  z y a b c
#1 1 1 1 1 1
#2 2 1 1 1 1
```

---

If we need to loop through the 'meta' names

```
for(cn in as.character(meta$colname)) frm[[cn]] <- 1
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun.  I tried it but I'm still not getting columns a/b/c. If you run this do you see columns a/b/c?

Comment: @sisdog That is strange.  I do get the a,b,c columns.  Updated the post

Comment: It was the scoping inside apply() that was the problem I think.  
Thanks again for the help.