# function environment within lapply loop

Tags: r, function, lapply, environment

so i came across this problem that is to do with variables existing in different environments and it left me very confused as it does not fit with my understanding of how functions look for various objects.

my toy example is very simple: i have a function `foo` taking one argument `j`. `foo` lives inside a function of an `lapply` loop with an argument 'i'. now, `i` clearly exists within the `lapply` environment (and does not in the global one). when called within the lapply function `foo` struggles to find `i` and throws and error:

```
foo <- function(j){
 message('foo env: exists(j) ', exists('j'))
 message('foo env: exists(i) ', exists('i'))
 i
}

env.g <- environment()
invisible(lapply(1, FUN = function(i){
  message('global env: exists(i) ', exists('i', envir = env.g))
  message('lapply env: exists(i) ', exists('i'))
  message(' ')
  j <- i + 1

  foo(j)
   }
  ))

#global env: exists(i) FALSE
#lapply env: exists(i) TRUE

#foo env: exists(j) TRUE
#foo env: exists(i) FALSE
#Error in foo(j) : object 'i' not found
```

when, on the other hand, `i` exists in the global environment, `foo` is okay with that:

```
i <- 10
foo()
#foo env: exists(j) TRUE
#foo env: exists(i) TRUE
#[1] 10
```

so my prior understanding was that if a function doesn't see a variable in its own environment it goes to the next one up (`lapply` in my first example and global env. in my second one), until it finds it. however, it clearly doesn't go to the outer loop of `lapply` in the above... why?

Comment: Good question. The only info on `?lapply` seems to be, "If expr is a function call, be aware of assumptions about where it is evaluated".

Comment: [Relevant post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar), [Relevant post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640157/how-to-access-global-outer-scope-variable-from-r-apply-function)

Comment: thanks for the links @RemkoDuursma !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is because function `foo()` is evaluated in the environment in which it is defined. In your example `foo()` is defined in global environment and therefore `i` is not in scope. If you define `foo()` within the anonymous function then `i` appears to be evaluated correctly.

```
env.g <- environment()
invisible(lapply(1, FUN = function(i){
  message('global env: exists(i) ', exists('i', envir = env.g))
  message('lapply env: exists(i) ', exists('i'))
  message(' ')
  j <- i + 1

  foo <- function(j){
   message('foo env: exists(j) ', exists('j'))
   message('foo env: exists(i) ', exists('i'))
   i
  }

  foo(j)
   }
  ))

#global env: exists(i) FALSE
#lapply env: exists(i) TRUE

#foo env: exists(j) TRUE
#foo env: exists(i) TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 types of environments associated with a function.

When you run:

```
rm(i)
lapply(1, foo)
```

or even:

```
rm(i)
lapply(1, function(x) {
  i <- 42
  foo(x)
})
```

the situation is:

`lapply`:

- Enclosing env: `namespace:base`
- Binding env: `package:base`
- Execution env: created on the fly, and enclosed in `.GlobalEnv`
- Calling env: `.GlobalEnv`

and `foo`:

- Enclosing (where it was defined): `.GlobalEnv`
- Binding (where the name `foo` is): `.GlobalEnv`
- Execution (enclosed in Calling env): created on the fly, and enclosed... I'm not even sure where, but when going up the chain of enclosed environments, there should be the execution environment of `lapply`
- Calling: same, not really sure... but it shouldn't matter

But:
(Possibly) contrary to intuition, variables are not found by going up the "call stack" *AKA **dynamic scoping*** (that would be: exec env of `foo`, (then possibly some intermediary environments), then exec env of `lapply` (where we would find `i <- 42`), then `.GlobalEnv`), but directly in the enclosing environment of `foo` *AKA **lexical scoping***, then the chain of its enclosed environments, thus bypassing the execution environment of `lapply`, and thus not finding `i`, even if it is explicitly declared just above...