# How to run script which is saved in my R session using Paste function

Tags: r

I have saved text using paste, now i want to run as code.

eg: i have below data

```
data

     a b c
[1,] 1 2 3
[2,] 2 3 2
[3,] 3 4 3
[4,] 4 2 1
```

I want to create subset data1 having a,b

i created a variable having a,b

```
variable<-paste("a,","b")
script=paste("data1=subset(data,select=c(",variable,"))")
script
[1] "data1=subset(data,select=c( a, b ))"
```

now how to run this as script and get data1?

Comment: Why do you have to do this way?  It is easier to `variable <- c('a', 'b'); data1 <- data[,variable]` or if it is already `paste`d, then `data[,strsplit(variable, ', ')[[1]]]`

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

```
eval(parse(text=script))
data1
#     a b
#[1,] 1 2
#[2,] 2 3
#[3,] 3 4
#[4,] 4 2
```

Comment: [but](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647046/avoiding-the-infamous-evalparse-construct)... ;-)