# How do I avoid eval and parse?

Tags: r, eval

I have written a function that sources files that contain scripts for other functions and stores these functions in an alternative environment so that they aren't cluttering up the global environment. The code works, but contains three instances of `eval(parse(...))`:

```
# sourceFunctionHidden ---------------------------
# source a function and hide the function from the global environment
sourceFunctionHidden <- function(functions, environment = "env", ...) {
    if (environment %in% search()) {
        while (environment %in% search()) {
            if (!exists("counter", inherits = F)) counter <- 0
            eval(parse(text = paste0("detach(", environment, ")")))
            counter <- counter + 1 
        }
        cat("detached", counter, environment, "s\n")
    } else {cat("no", environment, "attached\n")}
    if (!environment %in% ls(.GlobalEnv, all.names = T)) {
        assign(environment, new.env(), pos = .GlobalEnv)
        cat("created", environment, "\n")
    } else {cat(environment, "already exists\n")}
    sapply(functions, function(func) {
        source(paste0("C:/Users/JT/R/Functions/", func, ".R"))
        eval(parse(text = paste0(environment, "$", func," <- ", func)))
        cat(func, "created in", environment, "\n")
    })
    eval(parse(text = paste0("attach(", environment, ")")))
    cat("attached", environment, "\n\n")
}
```

Much has been written about the sub-optimality of the `eval(parse(...))` construction (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647046/avoiding-the-infamous-evalparse-construct) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025031/r-evalparse-is-often-suboptimal)). However, the discussions that I've found mostly deal with alternate strategies for subsetting. The first and third instances of `eval(parse(...))` in my code don't involve subsetting (the second instance might be related to subsetting).

Is there a way to call `new.env(...)`, `[environment name]$[function name] <- [function name]`, and `attach(...)` without resorting to `eval(parse(...))`? Thanks.

N.B.: I don't want to change the names of my functions to `.name` to hide them in the global environment

Comment: Just discovered that `eval(parse(text = paste0("detach(", environment, ")")))` can be replaced with `detach(environment, character.only = T)`. The question about improving `eval(parse(text = paste0("attach(", environment, ")")))` remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what its worth, the function `source` actually uses `eval(parse(...))`, albeit in a somewhat subtle way. First, `.Internal(parse(...))` is used to create expressions, which after more processing are later passed to `eval`. So `eval(parse(...))` seems to be good enough for the R core team in this instance.

That said, you don't need to jump through hoops to source functions into a new environment.  `source` provides an argument `local` that can be used for precisely this.

> local: TRUE, FALSE or an environment, determining where the parsed expressions are evaluated.

An example:

```
env = new.env()
source('test.r', local = env)
```

testing it works:

```
env$test('hello', 'world')
# [1] "hello world"
ls(pattern = 'test')
# character(0)
```

And an example `test.r` file to use this on:

```
test = function(a,b) paste(a,b)
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed that aspect of `source()`. However, if I change that line of code to `source(paste0("C:/Users/JT/R/Functions/", func, ".R"), local = environment)` I get the error `Error in source(paste0("C:/Users/JT/R/Functions/", func, ".R"), local = environment) : 'local' must be TRUE, FALSE or an environment`. Is there a way to convert the `"env"` that comes from `environment` to `env`?

Comment: You should create an environment to save into.  For example as I demonstrated with `env = new.env()`.  Then pass the environment as your argument.   If you need to name  the new environement using a character string (`environemt` in your example - although it is bad practice to use reserved words as names), you can use `assign(environment, new.env())`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep it off global_env, put it into a package.  It's common for people in the R community to put a bunch of frequently used helper functions into their own personal package.

Comment: It's not as hard you think!  I think the function you're trying to write is a lot harder and more complicated.  Lots of tutorials to write packages out there.

Comment: I haven't had time to make a package yet, but if [this description](https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/) of how easy it is is accurate, holy crap! I'm going to make everything into a package!

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:** The right way to convert quoted strings to object names is to use `assign()` and `get()`. See [this post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-May/021823.html).

**The long answer:** The answer from @dww about being able to `source()` directly to a specific environment led me to change the second instance of `eval(parse(...))` as follows:

```
# old version
source(paste0("C:/Users/JT/R/Functions/", func, ".R"))
eval(parse(text = paste0(environment, "$", func," <- ", func)))
# new version
source(
    paste0("C:/Users/JT/R/Functions/", func, ".R"), 
    local = get(environment)
)
```

The answer from @dww also got me to exploring `attach()`. `attach()` has an argument that allows specification of the environment to which to direct the output. This led me to change the third instance of `eval(parse(...))` (below). Note the use of `get()` to convert the `"env"` that comes from `environment` to the unquoted `env` that `attach()` requires.

```
# old version
eval(parse(text = paste0("attach(", environment, ")")))
# new version
attach(get(environment), name = environment)
```

Finally, at some point in this process I was reminded that `rm()` has a `character.only` argument. `detach()` accepts the same argument, so I changed the second instance of `eval(parse())` as below:

```
# old version
eval(parse(text = paste0("detach(", environment, ")")))
# new version
detach(environment, character.only = T)
```

So my new code is:

```
# sourceFunctionHidden ---------------------------
# source a function and hide the function from the global environment
sourceFunctionHidden <- function(functions, environment = "env", ...) {
    if (environment %in% search()) {
        while (environment %in% search()) {
            if (!exists("counter", inherits = F)) counter <- 0
            detach(environment, character.only = T)
            counter <- counter + 1 
        }
        cat("detached", counter, environment, "s\n")
    } else {cat("no", environment, "attached\n")}
    if (!environment %in% ls(.GlobalEnv, all.names = T)) {
        assign(environment, new.env(), pos = .GlobalEnv)
        cat("created", environment, "\n")
    } else {cat(environment, "already exists\n")}
    sapply(functions, function(func) {
        source(
            paste0("C:/Users/JT/R/Functions/", func, ".R"), 
            local = get(environment)
        )
        cat(func, "created in", environment, "\n")
    })
    attach(get(environment), name = environment)
    cat("attached", environment, "\n\n")
}
```